# Враппер представляет собой один dll файл?

Tags: c, pinvoke, c#

Для использования библиотеки, написанной на C, в C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит как от архитектуры приложения, так и от платформы =)
Можно одну сделать, а можно и десяток наплодить. Как разработчик решит.

И, добавлю, для каждой платформы (x86, x86-64, ...) нужна своя библиотека и свой враппер для неё. Такие штуки непереносимы...